# Question about my public_HTML folder permissions

Tags: web-hosting, server, apache2, shared-hosting, chmod

I have a shared hosting account that uses cPanel and I think su_php. By default, the permissions for my public_HTML directory are set to 750, which allows my site and all folders/files inside public_HTML to be viewable by anyone who visits the site. I'm assuming this is because su_php allows the server to run as my user, thus being able to process php, read files, etc, and serve them to site viewers; rendering any permissions for "other" unnecessary.

But if I set the permissions of any folders within the public_HTML directory to 750 (instead of 755) and I try to visit a page inside that folder, the browser gives me a 403. I'm having trouble understanding why my public_HTML folder can be set to 750, but folders inside it need to be set to 755. If anyone could help me out with this, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: FWIW, I'm not using suPHP and my `public_html` folders are also set to `0750`.

Comment: I think the important thing is that in this instance, the `public_html` belongs to a different group than all your other files/folders (the Apache UID I think).

Comment: Thank you w3d, I believe you are correct. I've edited my original post to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, you can post your EDIT as an answer (it sounds like a very reasonable answer to me) then you can accept it (you can answer your own questions). By _accepting_ your answer it takes it out of the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

W3D, you are correct. This comes down to the fact that public_HTML is owned by the group "nobody," of which Apache is a member. Directories and files that I create are part of my own group, and not of the group "nobody." So while Apache is accessing the public_HTML folder, it is a part of that folder's group, hence the need for only 750 permission (which is optimal also because it keeps other users on the same server from being able to view and access my public_HTML folder). But once Apache reaches a directory or file I've created, Apache is no longer a part of it's group. To that directory or file, Apache is actually only qualified as "other." Hence, the need for those directories and files to be set to 755.

Thank you guys for your replies. I can't upvote yet or I would.

Answer (score 1):

You can access files and folders within the public_HTML because they are not inheriting the 750 rule. Depending on your setup sometimes a child permission can overrule that of a parent, which I'm guessing is the case.

SOURCE: [STACK OVERFLOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547085/differences-between-chmod-755-vs-750-permissions-set)

> 0755 = User:rwx Group:r-x World:r-x
>
> 0750 = User:rwx Group:r-x World:--- (i.e. World: no access)
>
> r = read
>
> w = write
>
> x = execute (traverse for directories)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suppose it could be the case that, as you say, maybe with my provider's setup a child permission can overrule a parent. FWIW, I tried testing this by creating domain.com/test/test2/index.php. I set permissions: public_HTML(750), test(700), and test2(755) to see if test2 would override the settings of test, but it didn't and I got a 403 when I visited domain.com/test/test2/index.php. Maybe they have it set so only the public_HTML directory permissions can be overridden by children? Confusing. Thanks again for taking the time.